# Which rockets have their upper stages separating at(around) 100 km?

Tags: rockets, stage-separation, high-altitude-launch

Are there any current rocket systems that go to the Karman line with just 1 stage without boosters? Recent Rockets like the Falcon 9 separate at  80 km. New Shepard launches recently touched 100 km but it's unclear if the rocket staging will occur at such a  altitude. Old and big rockets like Soyuz and Ariane separate boosters at around 50 km but separate at much higher altitudes of 150+km.

Comment: If you consider the He balloon as '1st stage' then no -- balloons max out at approx 30 km.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on your definition of a stage. Soyuz' boosters cut off and separate at ~40km, but the core stage cuts off well above the Karman line, around 175km altitude. [This article refers to the boosters as "first stage" and the core as "second stage"](http://blogs.esa.int/VITAmission/2017/07/28/soyuz-launch-sequence/) despite the fact that the core starts burning at liftoff.

Single-stick launchers like Falcon 9 and Atlas V typically separate first stage at 60-80km altitude.